# Can I get a field if I disabled the _source and _all in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch [suggested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) to dissable `_source` and `_all` field in my case, this my mapping

```
{
  "template": "mq-body-*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 3,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "max_result_window": 100,
    "codec": "best_compression"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    },
    "body": {
      "properties": {
        "body": {
          "type": "string",
          "doc_values": true,
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `body.body` is a very large field(20k-300k), we don't have to index and rare get,this is lost-able. But after

```
PUT /mq-body-local/body/1
{"body":"My body"}
```

I can't find the body by `GET /mq-body-local/body/1?fields=body` or `POST /mq-body-local/body/_search -d'{"fields":["body"]}'`,the result is found one but no document.I know there is no `_source` I can not do `get` or `search`, but how can I retrive my document ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Elasticsearch's website:

> The _source field contains the original JSON document body that was
>   passed at index time. The _source field itself is not indexed (and
>   thus is not searchable), but it is stored so that it can be returned
>   when executing fetch requests, like get or search

Disabling the source will prevent Elasticsearch from displaying it in the resultset. However, filtering, querying and aggregations will not be affected.

So these two queries will not generate any results in terms of the actual body:

`GET mq-body-local/body/_search`

`GET mq-body-local/body/1`

However, you could run this aggregation that will include some of the source, for example:

```
POST mq-body-local/body/_search

{
  "aggs": {
    "test": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "body"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Will produce this result set (I've created some test records):

```
"aggregations": {
    "test": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "my body",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "my body2",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, may I ask how es store these docs ? still store into lucene ? How can I fetch body for a single id (filter?)?

Comment: Yes documents are stored in Lucene. If you choose to disable `_source` you cannot get the `body` field for queries. It seems like you NEED to have the `_source` enabled.